# How to disable private_mode with config update?

Tags: node, private-mode

Can you please tell me the command to disable private mode? I keep getting syntax errors, with e.g. `./tezos-node config update '--private-mode: false'`.

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible; the `config update` command does not support setting `private-mode` back to false.

You could edit the config file by hand, e.g. changing `"private-mode": true` to `"private-mode": false`. By default, the config file is located at ~/.tezos-node/config.json.

Another option would be to use `tezos-node config reset ...your options...`, which will reset the config (!) and replace it with whatever you supply.